# CSS double declaration (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found this piece of code on http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
</script>
 
<style> 
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 100px;
    display: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a working code.

I am trying to figure out how the script second CSS declaration block for the id #panel is working. Why didn't the rules from the second declaration override the rules from the first one right away but only after

```js
$("#panel").slideDown("slow");
```

is called?

Comment: Remove the `display:none` from the selector and see it already works. It feels like it is applied only after `slideDown` is called, but that is not the case

Comment: The style declarations are immediately applied, the second #panel immediately overwrites the first. jQuery's `.slideDown()` then applies its own CSS rules for the transition/visibility.

Comment: Not very clear what you are even asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page loads the styling applied to #panel is:

```
`text-align: center;
background-color: #e5eecc;
border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
padding: 100px;
display: none;`
```

slideDown() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and display:none in CSS (but not visibility:hidden).Hence, all slidedown method does is remove the `display:none` style-attribute, and your #panel becomes visible.